# Configure Jackson to use name property of @XmlRootElement

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jackson

I have a java bean that uses the JAXB annotation: `@XmlRootElement(name="beanName")`. Is there a way to configure jackson to use the `name` property of the `@XmlRootElement` annotation when deserializing?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've done to make sure that Jackson uses the @XMLRootElement of a class is to set the provider class to be `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` (rather than, e.g. `JacksonJsonProvider`). This can be done in a number of ways, depending on what JAX-RS implementation you are using, and whether the code is client side or server side.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is available in Jackson 1.7:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-163

See last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like this

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "SOMETHING_ELSE")
public class MyClass
{
}
```